# New user's question closed without explanation

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, etiquette, new-users

Here is the example of [question that was closed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/why-this-program-will-not-work-as-expected) without any explanation, without even trying to help [@Leon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22213/leon) (with only 1 point) to improve his question by posting some advice in the comments. I know that we have a FAQ here.

My question to you - do you find it user-friendly?

Answer (score 9):

The fact of the matter is that this is the third off topic question posted by Leon.

> Without even try to help Leon to improve his question by posting some advices in the comments.

This is simply not true. It's not like we didn't try to explain it in [several](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22799/implementation-of-a-linked-list-using-an-array-based-adt-in-java#comment35033_22799) [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/review-of-the-following-methods-of-a-binary-tree-which-contains-positive-integer#comment38013_24581). In fact, I tried my best to provide some [helpful suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/why-this-program-will-not-work-as-expected#comment38053_24639) in one of these comments:

> As Jeff and Winston explained, this is off-topic – **please read through the [faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) carefully**. If anything is still unclear after that, take a look at some  upvoted questions to get a better idea of what is on-topic here. Also: do some research about [how to ask](http://whathaveyoutried.com), your question is currently too vague for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). – [codesparkle ♦](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9390/codesparkle)

But it would be misleading to suggest that this question can be edited and re-opened as it is *completely* off topic.

To answer your question: *Yes, I firmly believe the Stack Exchange Network is one of the friendliest places on the internet, Code Review included.* We have to consistently enforce site rules to keep it that way, and that includes closing unsuitable questions.

(Also, I cleaned up the comments on the question you linked to as the place to discuss site related issues is here on Meta).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen 3 questions closed or almost closed this morning alone without any comment, one from a brand new user.

Putting a comment as to why you close (or vote to keep open) a question helps everybody:

- Tell the poster what is wrong/okay with the question
- Tell the other voters what you were thinking (sometimes I wonder what voters are thinking)
- Sets a tone for how this community votes, and why
- Prevent people like Leon from posting several off topic questions